# How to make a whole webpage fit whatever window it is on like a scaled image and be unzoomable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We used to have a silverlight page that used canvas to scale the page, this resulted in a page that would always be the size of the window it was on, making the whole page smaller if the window was smaller (it does preserve aspect ratio), as if the page was a single png but it isn't, it has dynamic elements. Also when one tries to zoom in or out, it does nothing, it just makes a scroll appear to the right and bottom without affecting the page.

We are migrating the page to HTML 5 with CSS, and we haven't been able to replicate this behavior. It is a page that has 10 small tables and each has 10 "messages" that can appear. When zooming in stuff starts to overlap in addition to change size, when resizing the window,stuff overlaps too but without changing size. Most of the positions are absolute but have % in their position onscreen. However we don't want it to be responsive, we want the behavior of the silverlight version. At least that's what the bosses want.

We have been researching how to do this but so far haven't really found a good solution, especially with messing the zoom functionality of browsers. most pages/forums say this shouldn't be done.

Edit:
For now I have added a bunch of max-width and max-height in the html style and body style, as well as added a media query for switching % left to px left for an absolutely positioned group of objects. However this is by no means whay I seek to accomplish. We need the whole page to behave like an bgimage, scaling every element with the size of the window.

Comment: use some absolute or fixed positioning for your main container, and make sure that all inner elements use '%' sizes everywhere (you can find tricks for the font size). Other option is to catch zoom/resize event and apply a 'transform: scale(xx)' to your content so that it always fits the view port.

Comment: Sounds horrible. People on mobile devices get tiny illegible text that they can't zoom in on. People on large desktop screens get massive text they can't scroll out of. Nobody is happy. Why not make your page properly responsive instead?

Comment: @RichardDeeming We know its not ideal for phones, but the requirement is that it needs to fit in this manner, its not a scrollable page, its a dashboard with values, in the case of phones the pinch zoom should still work because its an OS feature not a browser thing. so they can still view the info properly. For desktop no one should be able to change the size of the page under no circumstance.